# Fetch Result Crashes (using persistentContainer) - Core Data Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to fetch results from core data to display in table view whenever the view is loaded. Request does fetch the result but crashes as soon as view loads.

## with reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Since the introduction of Persistent Container, I couldn't find any reference about how to use it using Objective C.

I've a simple Core Data Model, 
Entity - 'Item' with Attribute - 'name'

// ViewController.m //

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
NSMutableArray *listArray;
AppDelegate *delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context;
NSMutableArray *resultListArray;
}
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
listArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
resultListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[self fetchItems];
}
```

## TableView Data Source

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [listArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (resultListArray) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [resultListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

## Get Managed Context

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
context = [[delegate persistentContainer]viewContext];

NSLog(@"ManagedContext Created Successfully");

return context;
}
```

## Save to Core Data

```
- (void) saveItemMethod:(NSString*)name {

context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObject *task = [[Item alloc]initWithContext:context];

[task setValue:name forKey:@"name"];

NSString *itemString = [task valueForKey:@"name"];

[listArray addObject:itemString];

[delegate saveContext];

NSLog(@"Save successful");
NSLog(@"%@", listArray);
}
```

## Fetch results

```
- (void) fetchItems {

context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
// request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObject *result = (NSManagedObject*)[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSString *resultString = [result valueForKey:@"name"];

[resultListArray addObject:resultString];

NSLog(@"Fetch successful");
NSLog(@"%@", resultListArray);

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: If you want to understand NSPersistentContainer watch this lecture: https://vimeo.com/89370886. This lecture is from before NSPersistentContainer existed but still very relevant.  Basically NSPersistentContainer sets up the core-data stack that the lecture recommends.

Comment: You need to run your app in the debugger and turn on exception breakpoints. Then you can see exactly where your app is crashing. Once we see the code where the app is crashing, we can debug why it's going wrong.

Comment: @DaveWeston thank you dave. i was having trouble to show the data on table view. now it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the `isEqualToString:` method is being called on an `NSArray` object - which obviously doesn't work (`isEqualToString:` is an `NSString` method).

So, your code is treating an array as though it is a string.  The root of the problem lies here, in the `fetchItems` code:

```
NSManagedObject *result = (NSManagedObject*)[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSString *resultString = [result valueForKey:@"name"];
[resultListArray addObject:resultString];
```

The first line is wrong: `executeFetchRequest` returns an array of `NSManagedObjects` (even if there is only one object in the array).  You can therefore just use:

```
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
self.resultListArray = [[result valueForKey:@"name"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have tried this earlier and yet again. still crashes with reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array', showing the array is empty. 

but in fetchItems method, logging resultListArray gives full array of items in output console.

Comment: i moved on and replaced    if (resultListArray) to if ([resultListArray count] != 0) inside numberOfRows method. app did run but not displaying any list in table view

Comment: @Rajxelton I'm unsure why you have two arrays, listArray and resultListArray, but I suspect the outstanding problem is that you are using the wrong one somewhere.

Comment: Even using one array for showing the list, i'm getting crashes. can you confirm my implementations are correct or not? I'm not able to find any reference for obj-c which includes newly introduced persistent container.

Comment: @Rajxelton Since logging resultListArray gives a full array of items, your persistentContainer / context must be working OK.  The problems lie in your  view controller / tableView datasource methods.

Comment: Thank you all. i've successfully resolved the issues. Removed the resultListArray, and saved fetched data into existing listArray. Later called the fetchdata and table reloadData inside viewDidLoad.